# AppleScript to clean spam in Messages

Tags: applescript, messages, spam

I get a lot of spam in my iMessage, such gamble, sex etc.

- On my iPhone, it can be filtered into a separate column.
- But on my Mac, there is no way to filter messages from unknown senders, which is annoying.

### iPhone

[image]

### Mac

[image]

### Question

Is there a way to write an AppleScript to clean spam messages that contain specific words? I can trigger it at a certain interval to clean up spam messages.

Comment: There is a bug in the Messages.app that does not allow you to get the contents of messages via Applescript.